# Merge specific github branch into gerrit

Tags: git, github, git-merge, gerrit

I have github repository in that i have many branches. From that one branch let's say `upstream_release` needs to be merged with gerrit repository branch. Even in my gerrit also i have many branches, but in gerrit i need to create new branch and merge my github changes.

Please let me know the possible ways to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Login to Github Desktop. Follow the below 3 steps.

1. In GitHub Desktop, click Current Branch.
2. Click Choose a branch to merge into BRANCH.
3. Click the branch you want to merge into the current branch, then click Merge BRANCH into BRANCH.

Note: If there are merge conflicts, GitHub Desktop will warn you above the Merge BRANCH into BRANCH button.